# Как использовать .format с шаблонами, содержащими { и } (например, JSON)?

Tags: python, json, строки

Задача: есть массив кортежей `(float, float, boolean)`. Нужно его сериализовать в строку в различных форматах, в том числе JSON. Хочу собрать строку для каждого элемента с помощью `.format`, а потом собрать их с помощью `', '.join()`

Похоже, что `.format` распознает скобки от json'a как обозначения ключей словаря:

```
json_point = '{"lon": {lon}, "lat": {lat}, "transit": {transit}}'
print json_point.format(lon=123, lat=456, transit='false')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/n.volynkin/workspace/.../test.py", line 9, in testMakeJson
    print self.json_point.format(l=123, lat=456, transit='false')
KeyError: '"lon"'
```

Крайне не хотелось бы велосипедить с `'},\n{'.join()`, это сейчас json неглубокий, а потом может быть любой. Есть ли возможность как-то экранировать те `{}`, которые я не использую для обозначения ключей словаря?

Comment: Правильный подход использует `json.dump()` вместо `.format()` для генерирования json текста.

Comment: @jfs гениально и просто. Вот каждый день такое с питоном.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фигурные скобки в явном виде в форматируемой строке ставятся так: `{{` и `}}`

```
json_point = '{{ "lon": {lon}, "lat": {lat}, "transit": {transit} }}'
json_point.format(lon=123, lat=456, transit='false')
```

> '{ "lon": 123, "lat": 456, "transit": false }'

Comment: Это подозрительно напоминает мне jinja. )

Comment: Кстати, а пробелы внутри двойных скобок обязательны?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не обязательны, я для наглядности так сделал в ответе :)